# Printing Two Different Strings in two Threads in Order

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to Write a Program where two threads are running simultaneously. One is printings Jack and other is Jones. The expected output is :
**Jack Jones Jack Jones** and so on. But I am facing issue while doing calling **notifyAll()**. Can anyone tell me what is the problem ?

**Exception**

```
Starting thread
Jack Jones Exception in thread "Thread-0" Exception in thread "Thread-1"    java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
at JonesThread.printJones(JonesThread.java:32)
at JonesThread.run(JonesThread.java:14)
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
at JackThread.printJack(JackThread.java:36)
at JackThread.run(JackThread.java:15)
```

**Jack Thread**

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class JackThread extends Thread {

AtomicBoolean i;

public JackThread(AtomicBoolean i2) {

    this.i = i2;
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            printJack();
            Thread.sleep(10000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void printJack() throws InterruptedException {

    synchronized (i) {
        while (i.get()) {
            {
                wait();
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Jack ");
        i.set(true);
        notifyAll();

    }
}
}
```

**Jones Thread**

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class JonesThread extends Thread {

AtomicBoolean i;

public JonesThread(AtomicBoolean i2) {
    this.i = i2;
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            printJones();

            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void printJones() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (i) {
        while (!i.get()) {
            wait();
        }

        System.out.print("Jones ");
        i.set(false);
        notifyAll();
    }
}
}
```

**MainProgram**

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class ThreadMain {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    AtomicBoolean i = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    System.out.println("Starting thread");
    JackThread t1 = new JackThread( i); // Will give chance to Print Jack first
    JonesThread t2 = new JonesThread(i);// Jones will follow Jack

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `wait` is that if you say

```
someObject.wait();
```

the thread will wait until somebody notifies `someObject`'s monitor.  Another thread can do that by calling

```
someObject.notify();  // or notifyAll
```

The thing is, though, the threads have to coordinate by using the same object.  You haven't specified an object, so your `wait()` is equivalent to

```
this.wait();
```

That is, the `JackThread` object is waiting for somebody to notify itself.  But nobody is notifying the `JackThread` object.  When your `JonesThread` calls `notifyAll()`, it's the same as

```
this.notifyAll();
```

so it's notifying itself, i.e. a `JonesThread` object.  So basically, your two threads are talking to themselves and not to each other.

It looks like you've set up `i` as an object that is known to both threads, so you could use that for your `wait` and `notify`, i.e. `i.wait()`, `i.notifyAll()`.  **Disclaimer:** I haven't tested it.